# Cannot run Docker with --restart

Tags: docker, ubuntu, containers

In short, when I'm running Docker with vanilla Ubuntu image and --restart option it works great:

```
docker run -it --restart unless-stopped ubuntu:20.04
```

I created simple one liner Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
```

And image out of it:

```
docker build -t market .
```

When I'm running it, works without any problem:

```
 docker run -it market
```

But when I'm starting it with --restart option (the same as in vanilla Ubuntu image) it fails:

```
docker run -it –-restart unless-stopped market
docker: invalid reference format.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Do you maybe know what is wrong here?

Comment: In your last command, the first `-` in `--restart` appears to actually be a Unicode U+2013 EN DASH.

Comment: @DavidMaze I'm burning with shame... I've spent an hour on that. Thank you.